# CSS issue for flexible width extended nav

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a site that is flexible width and needs an extended nav to display categories, like on http://www.backcountry.com/ but flexible and three levels instead of two.

The problem is that if I change the size to a % instead of set pixel width, it is only 100% of the parent li above it instead of 100% of the entire nav bar.

The markup is here: http://jsfiddle.net/lfischer/L6CGj/ but here is a simplified version:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Primary</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Secondary</a>
        <div class="tertiary_nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
          </ul>  
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Secondary</a>
         <div class="tertiary_nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tertiary</a></li>
          </ul>  
        </div>  
      </li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* primary nav */
#nav { position: relative; }
#nav > ul { list-style: none; margin: 0 3%; padding: 0; float: left; width: 94%; }
#nav > ul > li { float: left; padding: 0; margin: 0; position: relative; }
#nav > ul > li a { display: block;  }

/* simple drop down */
#nav > ul > li > ul { position: absolute; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0.5em 0; display: none; z-index: 9999; list-style: none; }
#nav > ul > li > ul > li { clear: left; position: relative; width: 200px; padding: 0;}
#nav > ul > li > ul > li a { padding: 0.3em 1em; line-height: 1.1em;  }
#nav > ul > li > ul > li ul { list-style: none; }

/* extended drop down second level */
#nav > ul > li.extended_sub_nav { position: inherit; }
#nav > ul > li.extended_sub_nav > ul { position: absolute; left: 3%; margin: 0; padding: 0; z-index: 9999; list-style: none; width: 94%; height: 2.6em; display: block;}
#nav > ul > li.extended_sub_nav > ul > li { float: left; clear: none; width: auto; padding: 0; position: inherit;}
#nav > ul > li.extended_sub_nav > ul > li > a { padding: 0.5em 0.8em; line-height: 1.5em;  }

/* extended drop down third level */
#nav > ul > li.extended_sub_nav > ul > li .tertiary_nav { width: 950px; float: left; position: absolute; padding: 1em 3% 1em; display: block; }
#nav > ul > li.extended_sub_nav > ul > li  ul { /*display:none*/ ; width: 18%; float: left; padding: 0 0 0.5em 5%; margin: 0 1% 0.5em 1%; list-style: none; min-height: 8em; }
#nav > ul > li.extended_sub_nav > ul > li  ul a { padding: 0.1em 0; }
#nav > ul > li.extended_sub_nav > ul > li  a:hover { text-decoration: underline }
#nav > ul > li.extended_sub_nav > ul > li  ul li { padding: 0; }

#nav ul > li:hover > ul, #nav > ul > li.extended_sub_nav > ul > li:hover  ul, #nav > ul > li.extended_sub_nav > ul > li:hover .tertiary_nav { display: block; }
```

The tertiary ul's are 18% wide to create columns and some of the display: none's are edited or commented out just for easier testing.

Comment: Percents are relative to parent's size, yes. So what's the question?
By the way you're using way too specific CSS selectors.

Comment: I stripped out a lot of the style declarations to post here. I need to make the .tertiery_nav 100% instead of 950px and it be 100% of the page instead of the parent li.